# Simple Rails Model - subscribing users to threads

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :user
  belongs_to :assignee, :class_name => "User"
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :subscribers, :class_name => "User"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :todos
  has_many :assigned_todos, :class_name => 'Todo', :foreign_key => :assignee_id, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :comments, :through => :todos
  has_many :subscriptions, :through => :todos, :inverse_of => :subscribers
end
```

I'm trying to get users to subscribe to todos.

I'm hoping that I can do @todo.subscribers and get a list of users back.

Questions:

- **Are my class relationships correct?**
- **What database structure do I need for subscribers, if any?**
- If there is a better approach, please let me know.

Comment: have you tried running this through the console to see if it behaves the way you want it?

Comment: Yes, I haven't added a table for subscribers because I'm not sure what the schema should be.

Comment: what are they subscribing to? todos? you should treat it as if the model was called TodosUsers.

Comment: That's right; so I need to create another table with users and todos? What should the table be called, and can I drop the primary key?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code doing what you want, I simplified your models but it should answer your question.

The example can run by itself wthout rails, to use it with rails just ignore the file heads

```
gem 'activerecord', '~> 3.0.0'

require 'active_record'
require 'mysql2'


ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter => 'mysql2',
    :database => 'todos'
  )


# Rails code starts here
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :todo

end

class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :user
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :subscribers, :class_name => "User", :through => :subscriptions

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :todos, :through => :subscriptions

end



# create a user and some todos
u = User.find_or_create_by_name("Bob")
u.todos << Todo.create(:text => "do something")
u.todos << Todo.create(:text => "do something else")

# display the todos for this user
p u.todos
```

And the associated MySQL schema is:

```
# Dump of table subscriptions
# ------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `subscriptions` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `todo_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



# Dump of table todos
# ------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `todos` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



# Dump of table users
# ------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```